# ADAL, Angular 6and protecting the MVC API

Tags: adal.js

I have created an ASP.NET core MVC API and added Angular 6 to the same project. I want the API and angular to be hosted in the same instance. I followed following step by step guide (microsoft-adal-angular6):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/microsoft-adal-angular6

This ensures the Angular part, and users are redirected to the Azure AD login as expected. However the API is not secured, will this framework only secure the angular files? If yes do you need to implement a serverside owin layer for the API too, or can you handle it all by using microsoft-adal-angular6?

Answer (score 0):

The package allows you to get a token from AAD to send to your API. But, you still need to add authorization to your API.

This package is only for the client side angular app.

You'll need to configure authentication in your API.

Check out the service app in this sample:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore

Comment: But the package has a built in interceptor as shown in the sample. I would expect that to add the token.

Comment: That's all client side stuff. Do you have UseAthentication() setup in your OWIN pipeline?

Check out this sample. https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore

Comment: @ThomasSegato did you actually find an interceptor in this package? If so, what the name of the import. I created my own cause I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: I found one called AdalInterceptor, but it didnt work. So I ended up creating my own and that worked:   providers: [AdalService, AdalGuard,{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true }],
   bootstrap: [AppComponent]

Comment: Wrote a post about it here: http://whats-up-sharepoint.blogspot.com/2018/09/angular-6-adal-and-aspnet-web-api-b2b.html

Comment: Cool. I commented on some of the stuff I did differently than you.